# Is there a _DEBUG preprocessor definition for Windows Device Drivers?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, driver, msdn, kmdf

Visual Studio is supposed to define _DEBUG for Win32 applications. It doesn't seem to be the case for Drivers... Is there an equivalent for this or do I need to define one on my own for Debug configuration?

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with a Kernel Mode Driver (KMDF) project.

Comment: Device drivers march to the beat of a different drum, assume nothing.  You must have DBG defined to get code generation from ASSERT, ASSERTMSG etc.  Not turned on by the VS2013 project template, VS2015 is surely the same.  Just add it.

Comment: The "DBG" definition should already be defined for the Debug configuration.